# Get sharper map edges for the directed graph using python

Tags: python-2.7, networkx, matplotlib-basemap, directed-graph

I have  a graph (shown in the image) which is a bit messy, so I would like something that would be little more visually appealing than it is right now. However, I don't seem to understand a way to make the edges of the Directed graph (It is directed as one of the ends is quite darker than the other)  more sharper. 
Here is the image,
[Image showing the graph plot over India](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTkeO.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=68,llcrnrlat=5,urcrnrlon=105,urcrnrlat=38, width=160, height=160, resolution='i', projection='tmerc', lat_0 = 24, lon_0 = 82)
latLonMatrix = np.load(open("../latLonRegions", "r"))
latLonMatrix = np.transpose(latLonMatrix)
x, y = map(latLonMatrix[1], latLonMatrix[0])
map.scatter(x, y, marker = '.', color='r')
covMat = np.load(open("ogCovMat"))
A = [] ; B = []; tempList = []
for i in range(357):
    A.append(i)
    tempList = list(np.abs(covMat[i]))
    B.append(tempList.index(np.max(np.abs(covMat[i]))))
    tempList = []

xtemp = np.ndarray(shape=(2, 1), dtype=float)
ytemp = np.ndarray(shape=(2, 1), dtype=float)
G = nx.DiGraph()
for i in range(357):
    G.add_edge('a', 'b')
    pos = {}
    pos['a'] = map(latLonMatrix[1][A[i]], latLonMatrix[0][A[i]]) 
    pos['b'] = map(latLonMatrix[1][B[i]], latLonMatrix[0][B[i]])
    nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, node_size=10)
map.plot(xtemp, ytemp)
map.drawmapboundary()
map.drawcountries()
map.drawcoastlines()
plt.show()
```

Comment: From the networkx documentation on drawing directed graphs: "Yes, it is ugly but drawing proper arrows with Matplotlib this way is tricky."

Comment: @Joel Do you have a better solution?